# Cannot attach cache device to backing device

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, ssd, bcache

I have an LVM and I wanted to use bcache to cache one of its LVs.  (Yes, I know I could use lvmcache, but I was having issues booting and I gave up using it.)

First, I used [blocks](https://github.com/g2p/blocks) to convert the LV to a bcache backing device (this seemed to actually work!):

```
blocks to-bcache /dev/my_vg/my_lv
```

I created a caching device on my SSD:

```
make-bcache --block 4k --bucket 2M -C /dev/sdc4
```

I then attempted to attach the cache to the backing device:

```
bcache-super-show /dev/sdc4 | grep cset.uuid
echo 'above_uuid' > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach
```

I then rebooted my machine (after adding `/dev/bcache0` to `/etc/fstab`) and realized that the cache wasn't running.

```
# cat /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/state
no cache

# bcache-super-show /dev/my_vg/my_lv | grep cache_state
dev.data.cache_state    0 [detached]
```

Am I missing something?  Is there another command I need to use to enable caching?

Why does bcache not like my cache device and not letting me attach it to my backing device?  Did I use the wrong values for `--block` and `--bucket`?

Comment: Did you register the hacking and caching devices? Registration and attachment are separate steps. https://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt

Comment: If I do `ls /sys/fs/bcache/`, I see the cset.uuid for my cache drive (as well as `register` and `register_quiet`) and I can mount `/dev/bcache0`, so it looks like everything was registered.

Comment: Do you have a script to re-register the devices? You should only need to attach them once, but they need to be registered every time you boot. Arch Linux has a config file for this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bcache#Configuring

Comment: If I try to (re-)register the devices, I see `-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`, which I think means they are already registered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this by re-creating the superblock on `/dev/sdc4`.  Looks like the  `--block 4k --bucket 2M` was incorrect and that's why the cache device wasn't attaching.

I cleared the superblock, then ran:

```
make-bcache -C /dev/sdc4
```

Now when I did:

```
echo 'uuid' > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach
```

it worked!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem:

```
make-bcache --block 4k --bucket 2M -C /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

caused the write error: Invalid argument.

Specifically, it was the --block 4k that caused the problem.

```
make-bcache --bucket 2M -C /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Worked perfectly.

Comment: Just had the same issue. Surprised the docs still haven't been updated

Answer (score 0):

First,  try some clean-up:

```
echo $cset_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/pendings_cleanup
echo $backing_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/pendings_cleanup
```

Use `bcache-super-show` to get the uuids.

Then try again to register:

```
echo $cset_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/register
echo $backing_uuid | sudo tee /sys/fs/bcache/register
```

The cache uuid should exist in /dev/fs/bcache if the cache device is successfully registered.

If your backing device has a `cache_state` of `invalid`, your backing data is in the mercy of `fsck`.

If `bcache-super-show` says that that the backing `dev.data.cache_state` state is `clean` and the `cset.uuid` consists only of zeros, the bcache device is in the invalid state and must be recreated. [[source](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018621)]

However, if clean, you could try force-starting the backing device without cache device:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/block/$dev/bcache/running
```